# Reactnative error, unable to install the application

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

So I was trying to create a splash screen in react native.
I followed the following article and after completing all the steps, I cleaned my gradle as well.

**https://medium.com/handlebar-labs/how-to-add-a-splash-screen-to-a-react-native-app-ios-and-android-30a3cec835ae**

But when I was trying to create the app again after doing the relevant changes. This was the error that was being displayed.

> error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
> Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

Since I didn't know where I was making the mistake, hence I have linked my Git Repo as well.
https://github.com/SMAmmar14/reactnative

Comment: You added java code in js file

Comment: can you highlight it where?

Comment: @MuhammadAmmar, the question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.